# java 8 inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, java-8, file-descriptor

i am running java 8 8u131 inside a docker container.

the docker is limiting  the number of files that can be open by the application:

```
  "ulimits": [
    {
      "name": "nofile",
      "softLimit": 10000,
      "hardLimit": 10000
    }
```

but i can see that the number of openfiles by this proccess are 17K.

how is it possible?

Comment: What version of docker compose are you running? Under version 3, it should be "soft" and "hard" not "softlimit" and "hardlimit"

Comment: it's above version 3.